# Как убрать лишние блоки в магазине WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Натянул сайт на WP и добавил блок магазина с помощью плагина Ecwid. Вместе с блоком магазина появились лишние блоки сверху и снизу. Помогите разобраться, в какие файлы вносить правки, или предложите другие методы решения этой проблемы. (Новичок в WP, не судите строго).

Ссылка на сайт: http://cb33457-wordpress-1.tw1.ru/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если вы уже скидываете картинки вместо кода, то хотя бы пометили бы какой блок лишний

Comment: Блок с дубликатом фото хедера и блок с поиском, свежими новостями...

Comment: http://cb33457-wordpress-1.tw1.ru/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%bd/

Comment: Есть три самых быстрых варианта где этот бред находится, если вы не меняли шаблон. 1) Смотрите настройки страницы, 2) Смотрите настройки темы 3)!!! Виджет, зайдите и посмотрите в виджетах, вероятно область содержит виджет.

Answer (score 0):

Если посмотрите код, то увидите :

```
<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area">
```

То есть это в виджетах. По этому для начала заходим в виджеты и смотрим области, где есть search, за ним последние посты, за ним последние комментарии и архивы, категории и мета. И ИЗ ЭТОЙ области удаляем все эти виджеты.

Как вариант:

Если это сделано через элементор или блочный редактор, то в редактировании поста, должна быть настройка в админке, выводить без виджета (не в элементоре, а в редакторе поста).